# Inode of a Directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

Can you show with some picture or illustration what does an inode of a directory in ext4 filesystem?

Especially, how is the list of directory entries (list of filename-inode pairings) stored?.

Comment: the inode of a directory stores exactly the same metadata as the [inode of any file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/dynamic.html#index-nodes): the file type, permissions, owner, group, timestamps, size, link count, the location of the data blocks (and probably some other stuff I forgot). It doesn't store the data itself.

Comment: also, I do recommend you consider inodes an implementation detail (though one that leaks into userland). The fact that Linux tells you an inode number for every file on a file system is not because every file system has inodes, but because Linux makes it *look* like it does. Chances are, the file system you're using doesn't even *have* inodes. "Unix-Style" isn't very specific. Unix-style systems use ZFS, Btrfs, even FAT32 for storage. I'm really not convinced any of their metadata structures really represent quite well what you seem to think an *inode* does.

Comment: so, if you want to know what is stored in a file system as directory metadata, you will have to be specific about the file system! If you don't, all we can give you is "exactly the information that `ls -ld directoryname` tells you, plus all the implementation-specific extensions, which might include things like extended attributes (used for free-form metadata, or ACLs, or SELinux context, or…), quotas, inlined content listing, indices, compression and or encryption information, subvolume identifiers…"